# How to ignore interactions inside tested method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

So I have complex rest controller, I want to ignore implementation and focus only on authorization aspects.

```
@RestController
public class SettingsController {

    private final Service1
    private final Service2
    private final Service3
    private final Service4

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("settings")
    ResponseEntity subgrups() {
        //impl using a service1/service2/service3/service4
    }

}
```

As I want to test only authorization I am looking for such test:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SettingsController.class)
public class SettingsControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(role="ADMIN")
    public void whenSearchingForGroupAndHasAccessToPolicy() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/settins"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

but unfortenteley as I have many interactions, my test looks like

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SettingsController.class)
public class SettingsControllerTest {

    //mock service1

    //mock service2

    //mock service3

    //mock service4

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(role="ADMIN")
    public void whenSearchingForGroupAndHasAccessToPolicy() throws Exception {
        //build some mock for service1
        //mock interaction service1
        //build some mock for service2
        //mock interaction service2
        //build some mock for service3
        //mock interaction service3
        //build some mock for service4
        //mock interaction service4

        mockMvc.perform(get("/settins"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

is there any patterns to clean up this mess?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like more of a design issue. Controllers should be as thin as possible. Your controller should delegate to a single service that executes all of the necessary business logic. This service will have references to the other services it needs to execute that logic.

You then need only mock that single service.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SettingsController.class)
@MockBean(classes = {SettingsService.class})
public class SettingsControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(role="ADMIN")
    public void whenSearchingForGroupAndHasAccessToPolicy() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/settins"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Comment: ye you have right, maybe i gave stupid example, so lets now assume that we are not speaking about rest controller but about some facade class. Instead rest methods we have metods in complex facade